# npm request or https module which is better

Tags: node.js

I have to use any one of the mentioned modules in my project for consuming rest api. I need to know which one will be better in terms of performance. I have gone through google but could not find any satisfactory answer. I will be dealing with HTTPS - PUT,GET,POST,DELETE methods.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS module has few features, but same features can be availed in **REQUEST** package as well.

Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.

I would suggest you use **REQUEST** module. because: (I would list down few features)

**1. Promises & Async/Await**

request supports both streaming and callback interfaces natively. If you'd like request to return a Promise instead, you can use an alternative interface wrapper for request. These wrappers can be useful if you prefer to work with Promises, or if you'd like to use async/await in ES2017.

Several alternative interfaces are provided by the request team, including:

request-promise (uses Bluebird Promises)
request-promise-native (uses native Promises)
request-promise-any (uses any-promise Promises)

**2. Forms**

request supports application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data form uploads. For multipart/related refer to the multipart API.

**3. Custom HTTP Headers**

HTTP Headers, such as User-Agent, can be set in the options object. In the example below, we call the github API to find out the number of stars and forks for the request repository. This requires a custom User-Agent header as well as https.

**4. OAuth Signing**

OAuth version 1.0 is supported. The default signing algorithm is HMAC-SHA1

**5. Proxies**

If you specify a proxy option, then the request (and any subsequent redirects) will be sent via a connection to the proxy server.

If your endpoint is an https url, and you are using a proxy, then request will send a CONNECT request to the proxy server first, and then use the supplied connection to connect to the endpoint.

etc.

I don't say HTTP is bad or less powerfull infact, request module uses **HTTP** it's just that its more handy and easy to use.

Comment: Thank you for giving so much clarity on this. One doubt I have , i am hearing people saying that request module is a heavy module as compared to https. I mean with https the performance is much better as compared to request. Can you pls advice on this ? I am mainly concerned about the performance.

Comment: Mousumi, `request` does not have performance issues, in fact it is meant to be faster and easier.
Hope I have cleared your thoughts.